# how to open cmd from gvim without waiting the cmd window to be closed

Tags: windows, command-line, vim, gvim, prompt

In `gvim` I can open cmd typying `:!cmd`, but `gvim` keeps waiting for the `cmd` window to be closed.

Is there a way to tell `gvim` NOT to wait?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Windows, you can use `:!start {cmd}`, see `:help :!start`.

On Linux, you can launch in the background: `:! {cmd} &`.